# How can I create a model that represents a spreadsheet?

Tags: django, django-models, formset

I am trying to build a table style app to allow tracking items in a spreadsheet that can be added to a branded website. My table would look something like this if using a spreadsheet:

| Customer Name | Customer Address | Producer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | 233 Main St | Greg |

| Company | Date Ordered | Rep | Date Received | Cost | Quote Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 7/20/21 | John | 7/25/21 | 500 | JDHP |
| B | 7/20/21 | Mary |  |  |  |
| C | 7/23/21 | John | 7/25/21 | 1500 | 584D |
| D | 7/18/21 | Mary | 7/22/21 | 400 | J5HP |

Effectively the idea is that I'd have a model that houses each Customer's different quotes. I have 2 categories of companies (public and private) that would each be tracked so I'm envisioning a large form that houses these three small forms (customer info, private company quotes and public company quotes). I would be including every company in every sheet whether we reach out to them for a quote or not so we know what options are still available if the customer requests more quotes.

I've been looking at the django formsets as a possible option but don't fully understand how they work. I watched some tutorials and read through the documentation but it seems like those will simply add a blank input after all complete ones already in the table. Is this a correct interpretation of how formsets work? Or would they effectively allow me to nest multiple forms within a larger form? Secondary to that is how would I implement this model? I tried company_date_ordered, company_rep, company_date_received, etc. for each company in my list but got a lot of clash errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to web development.

A few points:

1. It's been said, ["Applications age like fish, data ages like wine"](https://www.reaktor.com/blog/applications-age-like-fish-data-ages-like-wine/) - what this means is its best to focus your attention on your data models and concern yourself less with the application code itself
2. Spreadsheets are themselves tables - meaning you wouldn't build a model that represents a spreadsheet but rather you would build a model that represents a row (object) or elements of each row (objects) of the spreadsheet

That being said, given your example let's consider what objects we are working with:

1. Your first "spreadsheet" looks like it could be a combination of a `Customer` and `Producer` table - for this example we will simplify this to just a `Customer` table which will contain the field `producer`
2. Your second spreadsheet is a bit more complex, it appears to join `Company`, something like an `Order` and possibly a `Representative` (and maybe even more) - let's break this down into each of its parts:

**models.py**

```py
class Customer(models.Model):
 
    """ 
        this is a simple model that represents a customer, 
        it doesn't have any relations to other tables 
    """

    name = models.CharField(...)
    address = models.CharField(...)
    producer = models.CharField(...)


class Order(models.Model):

    """
        this table represents orders, 
        it will have relations to other tables, add them as needed
    """
   
    # fields:
    date_ordered = models.DateField(...)
    date_received = models.DateField(...)
    quote_number = models.CharField(...)

    """
        an Order can only be associated to one Company 
        but a Company can have many Orders
        therefore we will use a ForeignKey
        the same goes for Representative
    """
   
    # relations:
    company = models.ForeignKey("Company", ..., related_name = "orders")
    representative = models.ForeignKey(...)
    


class Company(models.Model):

    """
        this model represents a Company
        its related to Orders,
        but the relation is defined on the Orders table
    """

    name = models.CharField(...)


class Representative(models.Model):

    ...
```

Spend some time thinking about what your entities are and how they relate to one another. Once your data structure is well formed, you can start to build out interfaces for users to view, edit, and add to your tables - forms are a good way to start but they are certainly not the only option. Best of luck!

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I had started to get to this but the addition of the related_name field as well as the layout of the code really helps me understand this. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem - there are two other types of relations `OneToOne` and `ManyToMany` be sure to check out the docs to learn more and see which relation is the best fit for your models.